# How to get back UUID from an Activity in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth, uuid

I am currently working on an App for Bluetooth communication, the App is basically done but it is not able to connect at all. I suspect it is the UUID. I did a search on internet on how to get a UUID for a device and I found this code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.UUID;

public class DeviceUuidFactory {
protected static final String PREFS_FILE = "device_id.xml";
protected static final String PREFS_DEVICE_ID = "device_id";

protected static UUID uuid;



public DeviceUuidFactory(Context context) {

    if( uuid ==null ) {
        synchronized (DeviceUuidFactory.class) {
            if( uuid == null) {
                final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences( PREFS_FILE, 0);
                final String id = prefs.getString(PREFS_DEVICE_ID, null );

                if (id != null) {
                    // Use the ids previously computed and stored in the prefs file
                    uuid = UUID.fromString(id);

                } else {

                    final String androidId = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);

                    // Use the Android ID unless it's broken, in which case fallback on deviceId,
                    // unless it's not available, then fallback on a random number which we store
                    // to a prefs file
                    try {
                        if (!"9774d56d682e549c".equals(androidId)) {
                            uuid = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(androidId.getBytes("utf8"));
                        } else {
                            final String deviceId = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService( Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE )).getDeviceId();
                            uuid = deviceId!=null ? UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(deviceId.getBytes("utf8")) : UUID.randomUUID();
                        }
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }

                    // Write the value out to the prefs file
                    prefs.edit().putString(PREFS_DEVICE_ID, uuid.toString() ).commit();

                }

            }
        }
    }

}


/**
 * Returns a unique UUID for the current android device.  As with all UUIDs, this unique ID is "very highly likely"
 * to be unique across all Android devices.  Much more so than ANDROID_ID is.
 *
 * The UUID is generated by using ANDROID_ID as the base key if appropriate, falling back on
 * TelephonyManager.getDeviceID() if ANDROID_ID is known to be incorrect, and finally falling back
 * on a random UUID that's persisted to SharedPreferences if getDeviceID() does not return a
 * usable value.
 *
 * In some rare circumstances, this ID may change.  In particular, if the device is factory reset a new device ID
 * may be generated.  In addition, if a user upgrades their phone from certain buggy implementations of Android 2.2
 * to a newer, non-buggy version of Android, the device ID may change.  Or, if a user uninstalls your app on
 * a device that has neither a proper Android ID nor a Device ID, this ID may change on reinstallation.
 *
 * Note that if the code falls back on using TelephonyManager.getDeviceId(), the resulting ID will NOT
 * change after a factory reset.  Something to be aware of.
 *
 * Works around a bug in Android 2.2 for many devices when using ANDROID_ID directly.
 *
 * @see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10603
 *
 * @return a UUID that may be used to uniquely identify your device for most purposes.
 */
public UUID getDeviceUuid() {
    return uuid;
}
}
```

I want to know how to get the "uuid" back from this code? I created an activity for this code. do I use an Intent?

Adding more info... I am basically modifying the BluetoothChatService Activity from the BluetoothChat Example from Android. and I want to add the UUID to that Activity

```
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    // The local server socket
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
    private String mSocketType;
    //Getting UUID
    Context c;
    UUID uuid = new DeviceUuidFactory(c).getDeviceUuid();

    public AcceptThread(boolean secure) {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        mSocketType = secure ? "Secure":"Insecure";



        // Create a new listening server socket
        try {
            if (secure) {
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE,
                    uuid);
            } else {
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                        NAME_INSECURE, uuid);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "listen() failed", e);
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType +
                "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
        setName("AcceptThread" + mSocketType);

        BluetoothSocket socket = null;

        // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
        while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "accept() failed", e);
                break;
            }

            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (Dataservice.this) {
                    switch (mState) {
                    case STATE_LISTEN:
                    case STATE_CONNECTING:
                        // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                        connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice(),
                                mSocketType);
                        break;
                    case STATE_NONE:
                    case STATE_CONNECTED:
                        // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (D) Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread, socket Type: " + mSocketType);

    }

    public void cancel() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "cancel " + this);
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "close() of server failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// This is assuming you are in an Activity. You should provide an appropriate context.
UUID uuid = new DeviceUuidFactory(this).getDeviceUuid();
```

This creates a new `DeviceUuidFactory` object with your given context and then gets the UUID from that object.

Comment: I tried that and it gives me this error The constructor DeviceUuidFactory(Dataservice.AcceptThread) is undefined

Comment: I added Context to the AcceptThread... now it gives me warning The constructor Dataservice.AcceptThread(boolean, Context) is never used locally I also changed Device...(this) for Device...(c)

Comment: You'll have to post your code from AcceptThread, I can't tell what you're doing.

Comment: adding it to main post.

Comment: I undid the changes so u can see the code without errors... only uuid is undefined

Comment: You were on the right track. You had the right constructor, just make sure you actually use it when you're instantiating your thread.

Comment: when I modify the constructor, this line gets an error mSecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(true); eclipse is telling me I have to add a value before true, but if I put Null, the app crashes. what should I put there now?

Comment: Don't put null. Put a valid Context. That could be a Service, an Activity, or anything that extends Context: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: I am sorry to bother but I have no idea what value to put to Context... can you give me an idea???

Comment: I added it to main post. The problem I am running into now is that whenever I run the App it crashes and LogCat says its because of a Null Pointer Exception caused by DeviceUuidFactory

Comment: I don't know how many times I have to say this: you need a valid Context object. You declared c but never initialized it to anything; there's your null pointer. I think you need to review your Java fundamentals before you go any further.